# Google maps api v3 infowindow not showing on click

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I cant seem to get it working. I used this on several other websites but with this new one it wont show my infowindow (infobox).

Markers are in position and when you are on a marker he is showing the title.

I can post the code but it comes with a lot of php and is a bit of a mess.

This is the url:

http://intertyre.server170.nognietactief.nl/montagepunten

I use the exact same sript on:

http://www.tyfoonbanden.nl/tyfoon-dealers

Working perfect.

Dont know why this is happening so if there is someone that knows what is causing the problem. Please share because I really dont know.

Thanks in advance.

The code (I know it is a mess, have to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder;
var map;
var side_bar_html = ""; 
var gmarkers = []; 
var infobox;
function initialize() {

// Create an array of styles.
var blueOceanStyles = [
{
featureType: "all",
elementType: "all",
stylers: [
{ saturation: -100 } // <-- THIS
]
}
];

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var myOptions = {
zoom: <?php
                                if(is_array($postcodevelden) && count($postcodevelden) > 0 && !empty($_POST['address']))
{
switch($radius)
{
case "5":
                                            echo "12";
                                            break;
case "10":
                                            echo "11";
                                            break;
case "15":
case "20":
                                            echo "10";
                                            break;
case "30":
case "40":
                                            echo "9";
                                            break;
}
}else{
echo "7";
}
?>,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php if(is_array($postcodevelden) && count($postcodevelden) > 0) { echo $lat.", ".$lon; } else { echo "52.2008737173322, 5.25146484375"; } ?>),             
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
map.setOptions({styles: blueOceanStyles});

<?php
        if(is_array($adressen) AND count($adressen) > 0) 
        {
            foreach($adressen as $adres)
            {
$afstand = round((6371 * acos(sin(deg2rad($lat)) * sin(deg2rad($adres->locatie_lat)) + cos(deg2rad($lat)) * cos(deg2rad($adres->locatie_lat)) * cos(deg2rad($adres->locatie_lon) - (deg2rad($lon))))), 2);
?>
addMarker(<?php echo $adres->locatie_lat.", ".$adres->locatie_lon.", '".$adres->locatie_naam."', '".$adres->locatie_straat."', '".$adres->locatie_postcode."', '".$adres->locatie_plaats."', '".$adres->locatie_telefoon."', '".$adres->locatie_website."', '".$afstand."'"; ?>);
<?php
            }
        }
?>
document.getElementById("table_markers").innerHTML = side_bar_html;

}
function myclick(i) {
  map.setCenter(gmarkers[i].getPosition());
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: document.getElementById("infobox"),
disableAutoPan: false,
maxWidth: 250,
pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 0),
zIndex: null,
boxStyle: {
background: "url('http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/tipbox.gif') no-repeat",
opacity: 0.95,
width: "280px"
},
closeBoxMargin: "12px 4px 2px 2px",
closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif",
infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
});

function addMarker(lat, lon, naam, straat, postcode, plaats, telefoon, website, afstand)
{
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
map: map,
icon: "/wp-content/uploads/wheel-icon.png",
title: naam
});

                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
var contentString = '<div id="infobox">'+
'<b style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; color:#00377b;">' + naam + '</b><br/>'+
straat + '<br/>' +
postcode + ' ' + plaats + '<br/>';
if(telefoon != "")
{
contentString = contentString + telefoon + '<br/>';
}
if(website != "")
{
contentString = contentString + 'Website: <u><a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="http://' + website + '">' + website + '</a></u>';
}
contentString = contentString + '</div>';
                                infowindow.setContent(contentString);
infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
gmarkers.push(marker);

side_bar_html += '<table id="marker_list"><tr>'+ '<td onclick="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers.length-1) + ')"><a><h3>' + naam + '</h3>' + straat + '<br/>' + postcode + ' ' + plaats + '<br/>' + telefoon + '<br/>' + website + '<br/>' + '<u>Afstand ' + afstand + ' km</u>' +'</td>' +'<\/a></tr></table><br>';

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<form action="/montagepunten" method="POST">
                                                               <input id="address" name="address" type="textbox"<?php if(isset($_POST['zoekpost']) && $_POST['zoekpost'] == 'zoek') { echo " value=\"".$_POST['address']."\""; } ?> style="float:left; height:30px; margin-right:10px; width:100px;"><select name="afstand" style="display:none;">
<option selected="selected" value="10">10 km</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="zoekpost" id="zoekpost" value="zoek">
</form>
<br/>                   
<br/>
<div class="mapborder">
<div class="map-width">
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
<div class="one_third-last" style="overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:hidden; height:579px; width:100%; clear:left; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px; margin-top:20px;"><div id="table_markers"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, please post your code. The sites you link to may stop working, or you may fix the problem, making this question useless to anyone else having the same problem (because they can no longer see your broken code)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved...

Nothing wrong with the code but there was a conflict with loading google maps api multiple times.

Using Avada as Theme for website. For other users that run into this:

WP Dashboard > Appearance > Theme Options > Extra options page.

There you can disable the Google Maps Api for Avada and error is gone.